# Kibana failed to start on CentOs 7 after changing logging.dest

Tags: centos, kibana

When i change line 92 of `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml`

```
# Enables you specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
# logging.dest: stdout
logging.dest: /var/log/kibana/kibana.log # line 92
```

then kibana does not start correctly.
When line 92 of `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml` is commented is starts correctly

output of `jounarlctl`

```
sie 16 17:32:51 test.org.pl systemd[1]: Starting Kibana...
sie 16 17:32:52 test.org.pl kibana[3083]: FATALÂ CLI ERROR YAMLException: bad indentation of a mapping entry at line 92, column 2:
sie 16 17:32:52 test.org.pl systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
sie 16 17:32:52 test.org.pl systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
sie 16 17:32:52 test.org.pl systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
sie 16 17:32:52 test.org.pl systemd[1]: kibana.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
sie 16 17:32:52 test.org.pl systemd[1]: Started Kibana.ervice
sie 16 17:32:52 test.org.pl systemd[1]: Starting Kibana...
sie 16 17:32:53 test.org.pl systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
sie 16 17:32:53 test.org.pl systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
sie 16 17:32:53 test.org.pl systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
sie 16 17:32:53 test.org.pl systemd[1]: kibana.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
sie 16 17:32:53 test.org.pl systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
sie 16 17:32:53 test.org.pl systemd[1]: Starting Kibana...
sie 16 17:32:54 test.org.pl systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
sie 16 17:32:54 test.org.pl systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
sie 16 17:32:54 test.org.pl systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
sie 16 17:32:54 test.org.pl systemd[1]: kibana.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
sie 16 17:32:54 test.org.pl systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for kibana.service
sie 16 17:32:54 test.org.pl systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
sie 16 17:32:54 test.org.pl systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
sie 16 17:32:54 test.org.pl systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
```

I made this folder in the `/etc/`

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root          root             6 08-10 16:00 kibana
```

I start Kibana as `daemon`

```
systemctl restart kibana
```

`Kibana` is version 5.5.1

**UPDATE**

I tried making this file manually but `kibana` won't start after that:

```
    [root@localhost kibana]# ls -lh
razem 8,0K
-rw-r--r--. 1 kibana kibana    0 08-17 10:17 kibana.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root     78 06-19 15:26 kibana.stderr
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   1,4K 06-19 15:26 kibana.stdout
[root@localhost kibana]# pwd
/var/log/kibana
```

`journalctl`

```
sie 17 10:20:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Kibana...
sie 17 10:20:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
sie 17 10:20:07 localhost.localdomain kibana[10222]: FATAL CLI ERROR YAMLException: bad indentation of a mapping entry at line 93, column 2:
sie 17 10:20:07 localhost.localdomain kibana[10222]: logging.dest: /var/log/kibana/ki ...
sie 17 10:20:07 localhost.localdomain kibana[10222]: ^
sie 17 10:20:07 localhost.localdomain kibana[10222]: at generateError (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:160:10)
```

**No space is allowed in the config file.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason kibana doesn't know to create the logging file by itself. So you'll have to manually create it first and set the proper ownership. That can be achieved like this:

```
touch /var/log/kibana.log
chown kibana:kibana /var/log/kibana.log
```

Then issue a **systemctl restart kibana** and you should be good to go!

You can check the log by: `tailf /var/log/kibana.log` or

```
cat /var/log/kibana.log
```

Comment: That's weird, cause on my other `centos` `kibana` created `kibana.stderr` and `kibana.stdout` by the same lines as above in `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml` I will try what you suggested tommorow. Thanks

Comment: Stdout and stderr are totally different compared to actually creating a file on the server and write the logging to it. Weird or not, try the solution above and it will work. Just tested it on my CentOS 7.x server where I have kibana installed

Comment: What i meant is that i had automatically created these two files on one of my centOS 7 - but not on the other one.

Comment: I think you are in a big confusion. Please do read about stderr and stdout

Comment: Ok it works - i am not allowed to have space in the config file